# GitLab CICD Pipeline result as not expected

Tags: gitlab-ci, cicd

I have written a GitLab CICD pipeline. So that when the two file in repo `GKE` got changed then it should trigger the GitLab CICD pipeline in the other repo branch `feature/ABC-123-Server-Update-Component-And-Unit-Test`, named repo `Exp`,  while also passing that the file is changed in `dev` branch or `prod` branch.

Here is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file for the repo "GKE" repo:

```
default:
  tags:
    - docker

stages:
  - server-update

server-update:
  stage: server-update
  script:
    - |
      if [[ $(git diff --name-only $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA $CI_COMMIT_SHA) == *"lib/abc/argo-app.yml"* && $(git diff --name-only $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA $CI_COMMIT_SHA) == *"env/dev/mlops/tool/patch-argo-app.yml"* ]]; then
        echo "Server Updated in Dev Branch"
        curl -X POST \
          -F token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN \
          -F "ref=feature/ABC-123-Server-Update-Component-And-Unit-Test" \
          -F "variables[TRIGGER_BRANCH]=feature/ABC-123-Server-Update-Component-And-Unit-Test" \
          -F "variables[TRIGGER_PROJECT]=pro/Exp" \
          -F "variables[ENVIRONMENT]=dev" \
          https://git.swf.company.com/api/v4/projects/pro/Exp/trigger/pipeline
      elif [[ $(git diff --name-only $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA $CI_COMMIT_SHA) == *"lib/abc/argo-app.yml"* && $(git diff --name-only $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA $CI_COMMIT_SHA) == *"env/prod/mlops/tool/patch-argo-app.yml"* ]]; then
        echo "WandB Server Updated in Prod Branch"
        curl -X POST \
          -F token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN \
          -F "ref=feature/ABC-123-Server-Update-Component-And-Unit-Test" \
          -F "variables[TRIGGER_BRANCH]=feature/ABC-123-Server-Update-Component-And-Unit-Test" \
          -F "variables[TRIGGER_PROJECT]=pro/Exp" \
          -F "variables[ENVIRONMENT]=prod" \
          https://git.swf.company.com/api/v4/projects/pro/Exp/trigger/pipeline
      else
        echo "No Change in Server"
      fi
```

For testing purpose, I changed the files `argo-app.yml` and `patch-argo-app.yml`, the pipeline is triggered but at the I got the message that

```
/scripts-34677-15023504/step_script: line 149: git: command not found
/scripts-34677-15023504/step_script: line 158: git: command not found
No Change in Server
```

Although I changed the files but it didn't detected the change. What is wrong in my CICD pipeline ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: `git: command not found` is the error you should care about

Comment: You can replace all that if-else logic with CI rules: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges - which, coincidentally, also fixes the problem you have now (the build image does not have git installed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the issue was in my logic. I simplified it and divided it into two jobs:

```
# Stage to Trigger the pipeline when the Server in Dev is updated.
dev-server-update:
  stage: dev-server-update
  only:
    changes:
        - "lib/abc/argo-app.yml"
        - "env/dev/mlops/tool/patch-argo-app.yml"
  variables:
    ENV: "dev"
  trigger:
    project: project/Experiment
    branch: feature/ABC-123-Server-Update-Component-And-Unit-Test
    forward:
      pipeline_variables: true

# Stage to Trigger the pipeline when the Server in Prod is updated.
prod-server-update:
  stage: prod-server-update
  only:
    changes:
        - "lib/abc/argo-app.yml"
        - "env/prod/mlops/tool/patch-argo-app.yml"
  variables:
    ENV: "prod"
  trigger:
    project: project/Experiment
    branch: feature/ABC-123-Server-Update-Component-And-Unit-Test
    forward:
      pipeline_variables: true
```